# Issues in Converting values to UTF-8

Tags: java, php, perl, utf-8, pentaho-data-integration

I am encountering issues in reporting in displaying names. My application uses different technologies PHP, Perl and for BI Pentaho.

We are using MYSQL as DB and my table is of `CHARSET=utf8`.

My table is been stored with values in rows as below which is wrong

```
Row1 = Ãxâ€”350
Row2 = Ã‘zâ€“401
```

PHP and Perl are using different in built functions to convert the above values which is stored in DB and it is displaying in UI as below which is correct

```
Expected Row1 = Áx—350
Expected Row2 = Ñz–401
```

Coming to reports which is using pentaho I am using ETL to transform the data before showing data in reports. In order to convert the above DB stored values I am trying to convert the data through Java step as below

```
new java.lang.String(new java.lang.String(CODE).getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8")
```

But it is not converting the values properly, among the above 2 wrong values only **Row2** value is been converted properly but the first **Row1** is wrongly converting as below

```
Converted Row1 = �?x—350
Converted Row2 = Ñz–401
```

Please suggest what way I can convert the values properly so that for example **Row1** value should be converted properly to **Áx—350**.

I wrote a small Java program as below to convert the **Ãxâ€”350** string to **Áx—350**

```
String input = "Ãxâ€”350";
byte[] b1 = input.getBytes("Windows-1252");
System.out.println("Input Get Bytes = "+b1.toString());

String szUT8 = new String(b1, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("Input Encoded = " + szUT8);
```

The output from the above code is as below

```
Input Get Bytes = [B@157ee3e5
Input Encoded = �?x—350-350—É1
```

If we see the output the string is wrong where the actual expected output is **Áx—350**.

To confirm on the **encoding/decoding** schemes i tried testing string [online](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx) and tested with string **Ãxâ€”350** and output is as expected **Áx—350** which is correct.

So from this any one please point why java code is not able to convert properly although i am using the proper encoding/decoding schemes, anything else which iam missing or my approach is wrong.

Comment: What exactly is the actual expected value? "Áx—350"? You simply fail to handle UTF-8 correctly all the way through. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/476 and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for starters.

Comment: thanks @deceze, yes the expected value is Áx—350

Comment: the code you are using to convert is Java, not JavaScript no?

Comment: `java.lang.String` ... That is ***Java***, *not* Javascript!

Comment: Please provide the output of the SQL function `HEX()` for those values.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, HEX() values for  Ãxâ€”350 = C383C28178C3A2E282ACE2809D333530 and for Ã‘zâ€“401 = C383E280987AC3A2E282ACE2809C343031

Answer (score 0):

The `CHARSET` setting in your db being set to utf-8 doesn't necessarily mean that the data there is properly encoded in utf-8 (or even in utf-8 at all), as we can see. It looks like you are dealing with [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) - characters that that were at one time decoded using the wrong encoding scheme, then therefore in turn encoded wrong. Fixing that is a usually tedious process of figuring out past decode/encode errors and then undoing them.

Long story short: if you have mojibake, there isn't any automatic conversions you can do unless you know (or can figure out) what conversions were made in the past.

Converting is a matter of first decoding, then encoding. To convert in Perl:

```
my $string = "some windows-1252 string";

use Encode;
my $raw = decode('windows-1252',$string);
my $encoded = encode('utf-8',$raw);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was checking the encoding and decoding schemes and found from this [link](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx ) when entering **Ãxâ€”350 string to encode / decode ** as Encode with as  ** Windows-1252 ** and decode with as ** utf-8 ** result is correct which is as **Áx—350** So i am not getting although i am `new java.lang.String(new java.lang.String(CODE).getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8") ` trying to encode and decode with the same schemes i am not getting the desired results. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't know Java but I'm pretty sure your Java command encodes the string twice. it never decodes. I'm editing my answer to show how decode and encode in Perl